Canvas image not rendering
I am making a whiteboard collaborative app and I want the canvas Image that is seen on the current user side to be rendered to all the connected users in the room.
I am a bit lost here maybe because I don't get the exact workings of socket or canvas as I'm new to using them.
But How should I do this?
**
This is the client code-**
function Board({socket}) {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);//object reference with properties passed to a given object
  const contextRef = useRef(null);

  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);//state variable to check whether user is drawing or not


  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;//the .current holds the canvas object
    console.log(window.innerHeight+'/'+window.innerWidth);
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height =window.innerHeight ;// actual height and width
    canvas.style.width = `${window.innerWidth}px`;
    canvas.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;// height and width of coordinate system
    
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.scale(1,1);

    context.lineCap = 'round';
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    
    contextRef.current = context;
  }, [])

    
  socket.on('image-data',(data)=>{
    const image= new Image();
    console.log('Canvas data---'+data);
    
    // image.onload=function(){
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    image.src=data;
      context.drawImage(image,0,0);
    // }
  })


  const startDrawing = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    contextRef.current.beginPath();
    contextRef.current.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    
    setIsDrawing(true);
  }
  
  const finishDrawing = () => {
    contextRef.current.closePath();
    setIsDrawing(false);
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const canvasUrl=canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(canvasUrl);
    socket.emit('image-data',canvasUrl);
  }
  
  const draw = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (!isDrawing) {
      return;
    }
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    contextRef.current.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    contextRef.current.stroke();
  }
  
  const handleClear = () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        onMouseDown={startDrawing}
        onMouseUp={finishDrawing}
        onMouseMove={draw}
        id='canvas'
      />
      <button id='clear-canvas-btn' onClick={handleClear}>Clear Canvas</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default Board

**This is the Server code-
**
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
console.log('A user '+ socket.id +' connected');

    socket.on('login',({SocketID,name,room},callback)=>{
       //.........
    })
   
    socket.on('Message',(data)=>{
        //.........
    })

    socket.on('image-data',(data)=>{
        const user=getUser(socket.id);
        const room=user.room;
        console.log(room);
        socket.to(room).emit('image-data',data);
    })

    
    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
       //.....
    })
})

I tried to emit each mouse event but ig that will be too complicated.
